# Why am I unable to add data to django Model's objects

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

So this is a bit weird. I make a post request from the website I'm working on, I get the data on the backend but I can't access the model's field with the received data.

My Models.py:

```
class Records(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    Year = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) 
    January = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Feburary = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    March = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    April = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    May = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    June = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    July = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    August = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    September = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    October = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    November = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    December = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

My Views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def Attendance(request):
    data = request.data['list']
    
    print (data)
    
    user = Teacher.objects.get(name=data[0].split('-')[0])
    
    record = Records.objects.get(user=user, Year=data[0].split('-')[1]) 
    
    month = data[1]
    
    print(month)  # output is January
    
    return JsonResponse({'success':True})
```

So now when I try to print the January field of the records model,
I do it like print(record.January)

The issue I'm facing is that I can't do record.month
even tho month represents January

I want to add the data I got from the post request to the Model Field,
normally what I do is:

```
record = Records.objects.get(user=user)

record.January = "50"

record.save()
```

but as mentioned before record.month isn't working, rather I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Records' object has no attribute 'month'

What am I doing wrong ? Is there any other way to do the same ?

Comment: You might want a data model that's `(User, Year, Month, Value)` with an `unique_together` on `(User, Year, Month)` instead. That would make many things easier, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `'January'` is a string, and you cannot call method with a string. But you can set it with:

```
record.January = '50'

# is the same as:

month = 'January'
setattr(record, month, '50')
# or
setattr(record, 'January', '50')
```

And to get such attribute if needed:

```
month_of_record_value = getattr(record, month)
```

It basically translates string value of the `month` variable into a field name of record.

Comment: It returns me the characters that are in the field but what I want is to add characters in that field. So what I usually do is "record.April = 20 then record.save" I want some way to call that method with a string or some alternative to that

Comment: @VaibhavVishwakarma oh yes, I've edited my answer. That should help.